Is there anyway to run xcodebuild and specify the value of isysroot that it'll use?
I'm trying to build an Xcode project using xcodebuild, and I'm using a custom toolchain and SDK to do so. I can use the -toolchain argument to pick the toolchain I want to use, but no matter what else I do, it always uses the default SDK path (located inside /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/etc.) instead of the path I want.
Put another way, I want to specify the value of isysroot that xcodebuild will use when compiling and linking.
The -sdk argument doesn't seem to do any good, as it can only be used to specify an SDK that has been installed normally and resides inside Xcode.app. Even though the docs say you can feed it a full path, it always fails with an error saying that the SDK can't be found, so this option is either broken or not intended to be used this way.
I can't find any environment variables for specifying isysroot.
Is there any way to do this?
